# Convert if else to Pattern

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns

I am using Laravel to build a system, this system is very complex and it contains too many if else, I want to change and clean up the code to be easier to maintain.

I have something like this

```
if(A)
{
    call_a();
}
else
{
    if(B)
    {
        call_a();
    }
    else
    {
        if()
        {
            call_b();
        }
        else
        {
            if(C)
            {
                call_a();
            }
            else
            {
                call_b();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

of course its more and more complex.

Any help ?
THanks

Comment: What exactly is the pattern here? You can use a `switch`, and you don't have to enter "else", you can have another parameter `elseif(C) { call_a(); }`

Comment: Its hard to maintain this code, I put just small example of what my problem is, I have hundreds of if else that calling the same functions over and over, I am wondering if theres a design pattern I can use

Comment: Usage of a `switch` might be what you're looking for then. You can also do `$call_A= array("A", "B", "C"); if (in_array($value, $call_A) { call_a(); }` -- there's many ways to do the same thing, you just have to find the easiest way for your structure - and without seeing the structure of your code, it's difficult to help specifically.

Comment: Why don't you group the conditions with || (or) operator? For example `if (A||B||C) call_a(); else call_b()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know exactly what you are looking for. I really like [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/comments/3bcpcy/how_do_you_handle_too_many_if_statements/cskyox1) by [webstrous](https://www.reddit.com/user/webstrous) on Reddit:

> Now is the time to learn about ***polymorphism***.
>
> You didn't specify in your post if you were doing object-oriented
>   development in PHP. If you aren't, then you are stuck with the if and
>   case statements, but if you are, then you are in luck. ***Polymorphism
>   was invented, in part, to help eliminate exactly the kind of code you
>   are describing - indefinitely long lists of conditional statements***.
>
> The basic idea, in your case, is that whatever behaviour you are
>   trying to describe, which depends on the value of some variable, may
>   be better encapsulated in a class and its subclasses. From your
>   application's point of view, then, every instance of that class looks
>   the same, but internally, each object will implement a different
>   solution.
>
> Here's a quick example of inheritance in PHP, though depending on your
>   particular situation, other polymorphic approaches may be better.
>
> It is good to spend a bit of time reading about this. Don't think
>   about the code so much. Polymorphism exists in all object-oriented
>   languages, and you're better off challenging yourself to understand
>   the concept. Personally, I'm spending a lot of time reading about
>   JavaScript design patterns, because that's my domain right now, but
>   perhaps someone else can suggest a comparable book for PHP.